# Caffe loss layer - backward function

Tags: deep-learning, caffe, loss

I have a question about backward function in Caffe's loss layer. 
I have seen implementation of a Euclidean loss layer at : 
https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/examples/pycaffe/layers/pyloss.py

At the end, the **backward** function is defined as follow :

```
def backward(self, top, propagate_down, bottom):
    for i in range(2):
        if not propagate_down[i]:
            continue
        if i == 0:
            sign = 1
        else:
            sign = -1
        bottom[i].diff[...] = sign * self.diff / bottom[i].num
```

I know that **bottom[0]** indicates the predicted value and **bottom[1]** is target values (ground truth).
Can you help me understand why **sign** is +1 for prediction and -1 for targets? 
I thought that we didn't need to assign any values to **bottom[1].diff** for targets.

If I have multi-label problem, how can I update the code ?

Answer (score 1):

When `bottom[1]` is ground truth you should expect `propagate_down[1]` to be `False` thus no gradient is propagated to the labels.
However, if you use this loss layer to compare two **trainable** blobs you would like to propagate gradients to both `bottom`s.

The sign is only due to the derivative of this particular loss, write the derivative and you'll see where it comes from.

The one thing I am missing here is `top[0].diff`. If I understand correctly it should hold the `loss_weight` defined for this layer...